# Añadir datos a un archivo CSV

Tags: python-3.x

tengo un tipo de datos que necesito añadir a un archivo CSV, un ejemplo:

```
{'ACW': 65, 'ACA': 0.379, 'ACV': 237.2, 'PEAK_POW': 2.264, 'DCV_1': 176.0, 'DCA_1': 0.41, 'DCW': 72, 'AC_EFFI': 90.32, 'LINEA_DISTR': -402}
```

Este dato lo saco de preguntar a un inversor (solar, cada 5 segundos), el programa que utilizo lo almacena en lo que yo creia que es dato tipo diccionario

```
inversor = {}
```

El caso es que no logro que me funcione, copio hasta donde he llegado

```
    import json
    import csv
    inversor = {}
 

    headers = ['ACW', 'ACA', 'ACV', 'PEAK_POW',
     'DCV_1', 'DCA_1', 'DCW', 'AC_EFFI', 'LINEA_DISTR']

    file_csv = "huawei.csv"

    while True:
        ##......
        ##code that take the data from a Solar Inverter
        ##......
        with open(file_csv, 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
            writer.writeheader()
            datos = json.dump(inversor, f)
            writer.writerow(datos)
```

El error que aparece este este:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Lo que encuentro en google sobre este error no me aclara el problema ni su solución

La idea final que tengo es algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Ya se que el codigo tal cual lo copiado no funciona, solo pido que alguien me de alguna pista de por donde puede ir la posible solucion, gracias de nuevo

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver JSON si quieres grabar un CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás grabando un CSV, JSON no tiene parte en esta historia:

Este es la parte central de la solución:

```
while True:
    ##......
    ##code that take the data from a Solar Inverter
    ##......
    with open(file_csv, 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writerow(inversor)
```

En este ciclo infinito, cada 5 segundos se obtiene una muestra, se abre el archivo en modo *append*, se agrega una línea y se cierra:

```
65,0.379,237.2,2.264,176.0,0.41,72,90.32,-402
```

Como estás usando un `DictWriter()`, tienes que pasarle un diccionario para que pueda armar la línea en el orden dados por los headers.

Como sólo se trata de agregar al archivo, no de crearlo, la grabación de los headers debe hacerse en otra parte del programa.

#### Demo

```
import time
import csv

inversor = {'ACW': 65, 'ACA': 0.379, 'ACV': 237.2, 'PEAK_POW': 2.264, 'DCV_1': 176.0, 'DCA_1': 0.41, 'DCW': 72, 'AC_EFFI': 90.32, 'LINEA_DISTR': -402}

headers = ['ACW', 'ACA', 'ACV', 'PEAK_POW',
           'DCV_1', 'DCA_1', 'DCW', 'AC_EFFI', 'LINEA_DISTR']


file_csv = "huawei.csv"

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    ##......
    ##code that take the data from a Solar Inverter
    ##......
    with open(file_csv, 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writerow(inversor)
```

produce:

```
65,0.379,237.2,2.264,176.0,0.41,72,90.32,-402
65,0.379,237.2,2.264,176.0,0.41,72,90.32,-402
65,0.379,237.2,2.264,176.0,0.41,72,90.32,-402
...
```

Comment: De lujo @Candid Moe muchas gracias. Me queda que que aparezcan la cabecera, me lo quedo como tarea. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: @Karendonseisysiete. Al partir la aplicación revisa si el archivo existe; si no, lo creas con su cabecera.